# Find executables associated with Homebrew Formula

Tags: command-line, homebrew

Some Homebrew formulas have names that do not correspond with any of the installed commands (e.g., `coreutils`, `speech-tools`), other formulas provide an command that matches up with the name, but also provide others alongside it (e.g., `lua`).

Is there a simple way to determine what commands are associated with a given formula? Ideally as a `brew <arg>` command *before* installing, but even a shell script I could use post-install would help.

I thought I might be able to figure this info out with a `brew link --dry-run <formula>`, but that typically just gives me a warning that the formula is already linked (even with `--overwrite` or `--force` added to the command). I don't want to have to unlink each time I want to see the commands, so this route doesn't seem helpful.

Comment: Check out https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-command-not-found/blob/master/executables.txt

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As [bmike's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/203206/61338) points out, aside from digging through the projects source to determine what executables they install, there's no good way to determine what commands come with a given formula before installing it.

After a formula is installed, running

```
brew unlink --dry-run formula | grep "$(brew --prefix)/bin"
```

is a workable option now that `--dry-run` is available for `brew unlink`.

Before that was added I wrote an [external command](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/External-Commands.md) called [`brew executables`](https://github.com/SnoringFrog/homebrew-commands/blob/master/brew-executables) that still has some benefits over the above (mainly in formatting and handling some links a bit differently). I'll include a simplified (and probably non-working, due to missing some variable assignments) version of it here:

```
version_in_use=$(echo "$brew_info" | grep "$HOMEBREW_PREFIX.*\*$" | sed -e "s|.*$formula/\([^ ]*\).*|\1|i")

cd "$HOMEBREW_CELLAR/$formula/$version_in_use" 
for dir in `find . -type d -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name "bin"`; do
    for file in `find "$dir" -type f -o -type l -perm +111`
    do
            filename=$(basename $file)
            echo $filename
    done        
done
```

In short, it pulls the list of executables out of `$(brew --prefix)/$formula/$version_in_use/bin`. The version on my GitHub is a bit more fleshed out, including some added ability to identify/indicate when there are commands that link to each other in this bin directory.

Comment: Just a small improvement to the first command to highlight the executables themselves **if** you have gnu grep installed (`brew install grep`).   Command is as follows: `brew unlink --dry-run grep | ggrep --color=always -P "$(brew --prefix)/bin/\K.*"`  Output is as seen in [this](https://i.imgur.com/JTfZ4vd.png) screenshot.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote [Homebrew-command-not-found](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-command-not-found) to do the reverse thing: get a formula from an executable. There isn’t any easy way to get a formula’s executables as other answers pointed out; so I installed *all* Homebrew formulae and recorded all executables in one file.

You can [find it here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-command-not-found/blob/master/executables.txt). Each formula has its own line with the following format:

```
<name>: <executable-1> <executable-2> <...>
```

It’s as easy as `grep ^git: executables.txt` to get the executables installed by the `git` formula.

The file is regularly updated and covers 17k+ commands for 5k+ core formulae.

Answer (score 0):

In general - no.

Homebrew doesn't install package receipts which is the manner in which current tools decide what is installed where in an exhaustive and correct fashion.

Sometimes you can use `brew list` to check things, but I've found the best way to check on homebrew is via github - which publishes the source code for all the tools and all the packages.

My favorite search engine, Duck Duck Go even has [! commands to make it easy to search github:](https://duckduckgo.com/bang)

> !gh homebrew
> lua

Google does a decent job as well ranking homebrew fairly high as well as github

> !g homebrew
> lua

Also, `brew info` and `brew home` often give you a direct link to the project source to check if your suspicions are correct. As you surmise, the real check is to uninstall / reinstall and watch. Not fun, but effective.

Comment: Could you point me out to a documentation about those `!` commands?

Comment: I am so sorry for the delay @IulianOnofrei see https://duckduckgo.com/bang

Answer (score 0):

**I think the accepted answer is not (or is no longer) correct, precisely.**

While it's true Homebrew lacks the general feature you're asking for, there's at least one tap with at least two methods of using it:

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-command-not-found

Here's what I do! Method 1:

```
> brew tap homebrew/command-not-found
> brew which-formula when
when
> brew install when
> when
...
Fri 2022 May 27   4:40
```

Method 2: `eval "$(brew command-not-found-init)" # in ~/.{ba,z}shrc`

N.B. There may be some significant slow-down to shells with this 2nd method.

For that reason, I enjoy using `brew which-formula` (method 1) when necessary.